# Study about addiction to placebo

Tags: addiction, placebo

I was wondering if anyone knows about a study where people were given a placebo, then told over and over that it was addictive and would have terrible trouble coming off of it. It would be nice if these studies involved a brain scan as well.

I don't want to complicate this post, so I won't give my reason for asking this, but if you're interested I'll add it to the comments.

Comment: I've edited your title because the expression you used only hit some (unsavory) internet forum posts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a more systematic study, but I'm aware of some (old) case reports, best summarized in this 1978 [1-para letter-to-the editor](https://doi.org/10.1176/ajp.135.8.1000b) (of AJP):

> SIR: I would like to comment on the interesting paper ‘‘[A
>   Note on the Addictive Personality: Addiction to Placebos”
>   by Ira Mintz, M.D.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1176/ajp.134.3.327) (March 1977 issue). Dependence on placebo
>   might not be rare. As far as I know, I published the first
>   case report nine years ago (1). Similar descriptions by Czech
>   authors followed (2, 3). Dr. Mintz’ patients and my patient
>   were schizophrenic, but the other patients never have been
>   psychotic.
>
> REFERENCES
>
> 1. Vinar O: Dependence on a placebo: a case report. Br J Psychiatry
>      115:1189-1190, 1969
> 2. Boleloucky Z: A contribution to the problem of placebo dependence:
>      case report. Activ Nerv Super(Prague) 13:190-191, 1971
> 3. Honzak R, Horackova E, Culik A: Our experience with the
>      effect of placebo in some functional and psychosomatic disorders.
>      Activ Nerv Super(Prague) 14:184-185. 1972